# AngularJS - Controller and Service in one File

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

why is this simple code not working:

```
angular.module('menuApp', [])


.factory('menuService', function($http){

    var Menus = {};

    Menus.get = function() {
            return $http.get('/api/foods');
        };

    return Menus;

})

 .controller('menuCtrl', function($http, Menus){

var vm = this;
vm.headline = "Menu Card";


Menus.get()
    .success(function(data) {
        vm.menus = data;
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="menuCtrl as menu">
        <h1>{{menu.headline}}</h1>
        <p>Search by catergory:</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.category">
        <div class="ui divider"></div>

        <div class="ui grid">
          <div class="four wide column" ng-repeat="menu in menu.menus | filter: search">
            <div class="ui segment">
                <h3>{{menu.category}}</h3>
                <h2>{{menu.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{menu.desc}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

this is the console error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=MenusProvider%20%3C-%20Menus%20%3C-%20menuCtrl
>       at Error (native)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:38:7
>       at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:13)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:38:81
>       at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:13)
>       at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:283)
>       at $get.w.instance (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:75:451)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:58:476
>       at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:408)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular will look up your service by matching the name of the factory registration, so your parameter to your controller must have the name `menuService`.

Also, I'd recommend you [use array notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) in case you ever plan on minimizing your code.

Your controller line should look like:

```
.controller('menuCtrl', ['$http', 'menuService', function($http, menuService){
...
}]);
```

Comment: thx but then I got this error:
ReferenceError: Menus is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (app.js:22)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4185)
    at $get.w.instance (angular.js:8454)
    at angular.js:7700
    at s (angular.js:331)
    at A (angular.js:7699)
    at g (angular.js:7078)
    at g (angular.js:7081)
    at angular.js:6957
    at angular.js:1450

Comment: What's at line 22?  Do you have a reference to `Menus` when it should instead be the new parameter name `menuService`?

Comment: at 22 is:
`Menus.get()`